# Interpreting Coeficients of VAR Model as percentage

Tags: math, statistics, regression, var

I would like to know how should I interpret the coefficients of a VAR model as percentage. I mean, in order to see how much the variable X1 is influencing the dependent variable Y, what procedure should I follow?

Below there is an output example:

[VAR_EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k7ll.jpg)

So, is there a way to see the impact from "US_PROPANE_STOCKS" as percentage in comparison to other variables, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is not common to compare regression coefficients on a percentage basis.

You should rather focus on working with the regression coefficients by themselves. Here, you have to differentiate between raw regression coefficients (`B`) and standardized beta weights (`β`).

Raw regression coefficients are dependent on range and distribution of the predictors. Therefore, it is hard to compare `B` values of different predictors. For instance, your first predictor might have a range of -1000 to 1000 while your second has a range between -0.0001 and 0.0001. Given such an example, it would be pretty likely to get a higher `B` for your first compared to your second predictor, even though the influence of your second predictor could be much bigger. Consequently, `B` values are not very handy to compare.

In contrast, standardized beta weights (`β`) are (as their name suggests) standardized by having a value between -1 and 1. By evaluating `β` you can get an idea on which predictors have bigger influences than others.

But please note that `β1 = 0.25` and `β2 = 0.5` does not mean that the influence of `β2` is 100% bigger than `β1`. These coefficients still refer to the weights of your regression formula.